# AWS EC2 instance local storage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I created an instance of `m5ad.xlarge` of ec2 ,

[image]
 which should include a `1 x 150 GB NVMe SSD` but when I run `df -h` in the ubuntu box I got

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G  748K  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p1  7.7G  1.9G  5.9G  24% /
tmpfs           7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/7713
/dev/loop1       18M   18M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/1480
tmpfs           1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/1000
```

It only has 8G storage?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you can see is the EBS volume you created with the instance. You need to map the instance store volume on your instance before it's available. AWS has instructions for that [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/add-instance-store-volumes.html).

1. Connect to the instance using an SSH client.
2. Use the df -h command to view the volumes that are formatted and mounted. Use the lsblk to view any volumes that were mapped at launch but not formatted and mounted.
3. To format and mount an instance store volume that was mapped only, do the following:

   - Create a file system on the device using the mkfs command.
   - Create a directory on which to mount the device using the mkdir command.
   - Mount the device on the newly created directory using the mount command.

Answer (score 0):

It is dynamic allocation. 8 GB may be the minimum volume allocated for the instance at initialization. Since your instance is nitro-based, NVMe volume can be resized without stopping the instance. Take a look at the below from AWS document:

> If you are using Linux kernel 4.2 or later, any change you make to the
>   volume size of an NVMe EBS volume is automatically reflected in the
>   instance. For older Linux kernels, you might need to detach and attach
>   the EBS volume or reboot the instance for the size change to be
>   reflected

Comment: I don't think this is quite right, or at least isn't quite as full and precise an answer as it could be. Under the new instances all the file systems are called "nvme" something, and instance storage is only shown once it's setup.

Comment: @Tim Yes, maybe my answer is not quite right but do you know why that instance started with 8GB? If we always have to ssh into the instance and manually mount the device then it would be less convenience.

Comment: My assumption, without additional data, is 8GB is the EBS volume. 8GB is the default volume size for many AMIs.